# Table does not exist error in my Formula annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 entities : `Account` & `Transaction`.

An account can have many transaction and a transaction can be affected to many account.

This is the entity class :

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    private Long id;
    ...
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    ...
    private Double deferredAmmount;

    public Account() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }



    @Formula("(SELECT SUM(transaction.amount) FROM transaction LEFT JOIN account_transaction ON( account_transaction.transactions_id = transaction.id) LEFT JOIN account ON (account_transaction.Account_id = account.id) where account.id = id)")
    public Double getDeferredAmmount() {
        return deferredAmmount;
    }

    public void setDeferredAmmount(Double deferredAmmount) {
        this.deferredAmmount = deferredAmmount;
    }
}
```

The table `account_transaction` is created by the `@ManyToMany` annotation. I have this exception

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'account0_.account_transaction' doesn't exist.
```

Do you have an idea about the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure Transaction entity is alright?

Comment: When I modify my query to : "SELECT SUM(transaction.amount) FROM transaction" everything work well. So I think Yes.

Answer (score 2):

It means that in your database there is no table 'account0_.account_transaction'.
You can create it manually or change persistence.xml setting (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto) to allow Hibernate to create it for you.

If you don't want to have a table with name taken from the fields names you can explicitly specify the names using @JoinTable annotation.

Comment: The table is created but I can't use it in the Formula annotation.

Comment: Also make sure that table is in the correct schema. Are you sure that account_transaction table is inside account0_ schema?

Comment: account_transaction is in the same schema as Account & Transaction. I don't know why in the Formula annotion add the account0_ schema.